# How to find a definition of a class field?

Tags: python, oop

In a constructor of a class I see that some self variables are used without being initialized. For example:

```
def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x + self.y
```

In the above example, as you can see, `self.y` is used without being initialized. My assumption is that the value of this field is coming from the super class.

Hover, in the super class I also do not see a definition of `self.y`. So, where can it come from?

**ADDED**

I need to add that this field is not defined as a "class attribute" as well. So, I have something like this:

```
class MyClass(SomeBaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.aaa = self.bbb + self.ccc
        # some other code
```

**ADDED 2**

For the check I did the following:

```
class MyClass(SomeBaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        print(self.__dict__) # <--- please notice this line !!!!!!!!!
        self.aaa = self.bbb + self.ccc
        # some other code
```

and, as a result, I see a dictionary with keys and values. So, my assumptions is that these values are coming from the base class. However, if I go to the base class, and add prints to the constructor

```
def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    print('some additional print in the beginning')
    # some code here
    print('print at the end of the constructor')
```

then I do not see these prints (as if the constructor of the base class is not executed).

Comment: Bootless speculation is. Grep through the codebase you must.

Comment: Does it even work or do you get something like `NameError: y is not defined`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, it works.

Answer (score 1):

if `self.y` is not assigned in the `__init__` before, then this only can be a `class-attribute` (possibly inherited). `self` usally indicates the instance of a class, but `instance-attributes` are first **init**ialised in the `init()`. If it's not there, it's not an `instance-attribute`, at this point.

Example:

```
class test :
    y = 7  # scope: class
    def __init__( self ):
        self.x = self.y + 1  # scope: instance

a = test()
a.x  # 8   # scope: instance
a.y  # 7   # scope: instance, pulled from class
test.y # 7   # scope: class
```

For your studys: [In Python, it’s all about the attributes](http://blog.lerner.co.il/python-attributes/)
(*the best explanation about the difference between class and instance attributes, that I found so far*)

Comment: I guess it is not my case. I do not see any class-attributes (for more details you can check the extension of my question).

Comment: @Roman and what about class-attributes of `SomeBaseClass`? Inherited class-attributes will work as well. I'm pretty sure on this answer

Comment: @Roman only other option is see is that a class-attribute was set somewhere else in the code, after the class defintion and before usage/inheritance

Comment: please see yet another extension of my question. I do look into the base class (it was my first assumption, that the fields are defined there) but I do not see these definitions there.

Comment: @Roman sorry to ride about this point, but if you are looking for a `class-attribute`, you have do search these NOT inside the `init` (like you are adding to the question), but in the class definition itselve - same level as the defintion of the `__init__`-function

Comment: why do you think that I need to look for class attributes? I am searching for the origin of self.y variable. The fact that it starts with "self" indicates that it is an attribute of an instance. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Roman your rigth. It "indicates" it, but have a look at my answer and you will see, that that is not a "rule"

Comment: I do not have any attributes defined on the scope of the class (on the same level as __init__) (neither in the considered class, nor in the base class).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165290/discussion-between-skandix-and-roman).

Answer (score 1):

If you override **init**, the **init** methods of the base classes are not executed. You have to explicitly call super().**init**() in your **init** to do that. If you want to find out which classes are used to find instance attributes do: `MyClass.mro()`. The list you will get is searched from left to right by `__getattribute__` as far as I know.

Comment: Good point! The constructor of the super class is called but in the last row of the constructor. So, the attribute whose origin I am searching cannot come from the supper class.

Answer (score 1):

I there are some `self.*` attributes in the constructor of a class, they can come either from parent class (super class) **or a child class**.

If `super().__init__()` was not called from the constructor of the considered class, then definition done in the constructor of the parent class are not implemented yet. So, the attribute cannot come from the parent class.

What can also happen is that some child class makes some definitions in its constructor (for example some attributes has been introduced) and then a constructor of its parent class is called (which means that constructor of your class is called). In this case your class will see the attributes that are defined in the child class. They will be seen as its own attributes.

For example:

```
class your_class():

    def __init__(self):
        print self.x # How can we print self.x if it does not exist?

class child_class():

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        super().__init__() # here is constructor of the parent class (your_class) is called and this constructor will see self.x defined here.
```